# cant launch tor after install (Debian 10)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux, error, debian

Trying to start Tor for first time after install.

The first problem Ive got was the non permission to my user in the tor directory at /Downloads, so used root account to set normal privileges.

Now can open dir and its files, but while execute "start-tor-browser" appears a warning window:

> do not open if dont trust app
>
> tor its in an insecure directory and its not marked as executable

the next is an Exec code with its dir.

I select launch, and its supposed to execute but nothing happends.

The Tor Browser icon doesnt appears in the Internet app section as the rest of browsers.

Know what can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open it from the command line.

First cd to the directory where you extracted Tor Browser

```
chmod +x start-tor-browser
```

start Tor Browser

```
./start-tor-browser
```

It will not appear in your menu because you will have to put it there manually. Check help with Debian on how to do that.

Alternative directions:

```
sudo apt-get install torbrowser-launcher
```

Start Tor Browser from your menu (it is there now). It will automatically download Tor Browser and set it up for you. The version that you downloaded the first time can be deleted.